# Массивы 4-го порядка со случайными числами

Tags: python, матрицы

Задание:
Выполнить решение матричных уравнений A*X*B = C+D. Неизвестной в условии считается матрица X. Матрицы А, В, С, D – квадратные матрицы четвертого порядка. Элементы матриц генерируются случайным образом из заданного диапазона [2;9].

Первые 4 ячейки кода - матрицы A-D со случайными значениями диапазона [2;9].
5-я ячейка - облегчение для матрицы X, иначе после np.array была бы неразбериха со скобками.

Вопрос: почему 6-я ячейка не хочет работать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `[X15]`, наверное, а не `X[15]`, но вообще это всё проще гораздо наверняка делается )  Вы можете сразу "заказать" нужную форму массива, указав параметр `size`, т.е. что-то типа `A = random.uniform(2, 9, (4, 4))` в вашем случае, например.

Comment: Пишет: uniform() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Comment: Я у вас и скопировал
Вот то, что сейчас написано: 

A = random.uniform(2, 9, (4, 4))
print(A)

Comment: за код в вопросе в виде скриншота ловите "минус".

Comment: А, пардон, я не подумал, что вы внутри `numpy` обычный `random` используете. Правильно так: `A = np.random.uniform(2, 9, (4, 4))`

Comment: Вот это работает, спасибо, оставлю на заметку.

Comment: @strawdog извиняюсь, я здесь новичок, не подумал об этом, хотя это реально бы упростило всем задачу...

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ошибку, слишком много квадратных скобок. Члены матрицы отделяются в одной строке только запятой, а не каждый в скобках, а потом запятая.